# OneToOne Mapping - Play Framework Entity

Tags: jpa, playframework

I'm struggling to successfully implement a OneToOne mapping on my play framework application.

examples I have are:

```
@Entity
  public class Profile extends GenericModel {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "foreignGenerator")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "foreignGenerator", strategy = "foreign", 
            parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "user"))
  public static int id;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy="profile",  cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  public static User user;
}
```

and :

```
@Entity
  public class User extends Model {

  @Required
  public String firstName;

  @Required
  public String surname;
 }
```

in this setup it throws:

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: models.Profile

**EDIT**: As per [Christian Boariu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8561232/444991), I have modified Profile to what you have suggested and User to:

```
    @Entity
  public class User extends GenericModel {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public Long user_id;

@Required
public String firstName;

@Required
public String surname;

@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "profile_id")
public Profile profile;

public Profile getProfile() {
    return profile;
}

public void setProfile(Profile profile) {
    this.profile = profile;
}   
 }
```

Also added getter/setter to Profile:

```
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
```

But I am now getting `hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class models.Profile`.. not sure how to correct?

Comment: I also suggest to extend both of class from Model and in this case you no longer has to declare id field, because Model super class will do this job for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is about your Id definition.

It should **not** be `static`.

Also, user should not be static as well.

**UPDATE**:

So your class should be like this:

```
  @Entity
  public class Profile extends GenericModel {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "foreignGenerator")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "foreignGenerator", strategy = "foreign", 
            parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "user"))
  public int id;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy="profile",  cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  public User user;
}
```

Comment: fab yes id on profile should not be static. Also what do yo mean when you say user should not be static?

Comment: it means: remove static keyword from user field

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. suggesstions, as above fixed the @OneToOne issue and the hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class models.Profile was due to trying to persist an entity with a null id - due to using @primaryKeyJoin, so changed to @JoinColumn