# Play Framework, OneToOne relationship not working

Tags: java, sql, database, jpa, playframework

I am using [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/)(Java flavor) for a project. In this project I have two models which I would like to create a `OneToOne` relationship between.

I have a `User` model and a `UserLegalName` model. I would like each `User` to have a `UserLegalName` model.

[`User` model code](http://pastebin.com/UKkTwmNg)
[`UserLegalName` model code](http://pastebin.com/qvu2EYiP)

The issue is that the `User` and the `UserLegalName` do not seam to getting "related"
[image: UserLegalName Table]
The `user_user_id` column is always `NULL`. I have tried `JoinColumn(name = "user_id")` for the `User` in `UserLegalName` but this does not work either
[image: UserLegalName Table]

## Edit:

After taking @Sivakumar answer and fixing my code the `UserLegalName` is now storing correctly
[image: UserLegalName Table]
However when I attempt to get the `UserLegalName` for a user, it still turns up `null`

```
User.find.where().eq("userId", userId).findUnique()
```

Which returns

```
{"userId":"f5ea6d1d-d22d-4127-b6e7-0b3d0446edfe","legalName":null}
```

## Edit 2:

You can add `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` to the `OneToOne` annotation in the `User` model and that will fetch the `UserLegalName` every time. However in reality the `User` model is much more complicated. It holds many more relationships.

Is there a different way to do this? By keeping the fetch type as `EAGER` it could create inefficient queries(EX: I only want the users email, in a separate table, but it also queries the `User_Legal_Name` table)

Comment: Have you tried solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560988/onetoone-mapping-play-framework-enitity ?

Comment: The problem should be in your code, not mapping, so show us the code that you use for saving a UserLegalName. Also please show in your question, from what DB tables you should the data.

Comment: Please note that I answered first, pointing to saving correctly the entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used both your models as you posted in the above link and tested successfully. As @Andrei mentioned in his comment the problem is not in mapping, it should be the way you saving them. Following are the code snippets i used for testing.

**User**

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model{

    / ..... fields as it is in your post

    public User(String user_id){
        this.userId = user_id;
    }

    public static Finder<Long, User> find = new Finder<Long, User>(Long.class, User.class)

    public static User findByUserID(String user_id){

       /* Your models already in bi-directional relationship, so there is no need for external `fetch`, You can directly get `UserLegalName` object from `User`
               model if there is any match found on `UserLegalName` for the input.  */

       return find.where().eq("userId",user_id).findUnique();
    }
}
```

**UserLegalName**

```
@Entity
public class UserLegalName extends Model {

    / ..... fields as it is in your post

    public UserLegalName(User user_id, String first_name, String last_name){
        this.user = user_id;
        this.firstName = first_name;
        this.lastName = last_name;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class TestController extends Controller {

    public static Result insertUser(String user_id, String fname, String lname)
    {
        User user = new User(user_id);
        UserLegalName legal = new UserLegalName(user,fname,lname);
        user.legalName = legal;
        user.save();

        return ok(user.legalName.firstName);
    }

    public static Result getUser(String user_id)
    {
        User user = User.findByUserID(user_id);

        return ok(user.legalName.firstName);
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
GET      /test/:userID/:fname/:lname       controllers.TestController.insertUser(userID : String, fname : String, lname : String)

GET      /user/:userID       controllers.TestController.getUser(userID : String)
```

Comment: How would you query this from the db? Currently I am doing `User.find.fetch("legalName").where().eq("userId", "...").findUnique()` but `legalName` is still null. However if I query the `UserLegalName` table where `user_id` is `...` it will work.

Comment: @NoahHuppert I updated my answer with additional code snippets to retrieve user.

Comment: That does not seam to work. See edited question for more information.

Comment: Include fetch type for legalName field in User model. @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user",fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

Comment: @NoahHuppert Setting the fetch type to `EAGER` will immediately fetch child along with parent entity. Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you set only one side of the relationship, and not both. As you have a bidirectional relationship you should set them both before persisting/merging, like:

```
userLegalName.setUser(user);
user.setUserLegalName(userLegalName);
entityManager.persist(userLegalName);
entityManager.persist(user);
```